# How can I use the Apache Ignite.NET Thin client to connect to a specific grid

Tags: ignite

The Server and Client (`setclientmode(true)`) modes need Java and take quite a while to startup (`Ignition.Start`). The server is the one that holds the cache. I presume that the client node is like a 'local' copy of the cache.

However, Ignite also supports a ThinClient - where we can 'open a connection' and run queries from `Ignite.NET` without having Java installed. The only configuration required by a ThinClient is the Host IP Address. How can we connect to a specific grid on the ignite server using the Thin Client?

Is this something that is expected to come in the upcoming releases?

Answer (score 1):

Every server node is listening to some specific port for connections from thin clients. By default this is port 10800, but it can be changed. If this port is occupied, then next available is used.

So, if you want to connect to some specific node, then you should specify its IP and port, that will be used for connection.

Documentation: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/thin-client#section-configuring-server-nodes

Comment: Within each node, we can have multiple grids. In this config sample https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/configuration the gridName is grid1. I think this is called igniteInstanceName going forward. But with the thin client, we can only connect to the node, but not to a grid within that node.

Comment: Looks like you confuse terms "ignite node" and a "physical machine". You can run multiple Ignite nodes on a single machine and even in single JVM. Each node will bind to its own port.